# Will a 5nm diameter uncharged object make it through the renal glomerular filtration apparatus in humans?

Tags: physiology, human-anatomy, kidney, renal-physiology

Will a 5nm diameter uncharged object make it through the glomerular filtration apparatus in humans? I think that it should as I have read that the smallest fenestrations are about 10-15nm in size and if the object is uncharged, I would think that it would be unaffected by the charge of the filtration apparatus. Any thoughts?